# Server utility: receive HTTPS POST requests, cat the data

Tags: http, https, openssl, netcat

To test something, I want to run a simple web server that:

- Will listen for HTTPS POST requests
- Print the POST data received to STDOUT (along with other stuff, potentially, so it's fine if it just cats the whole HTTP request)

Is there a quick way to set something like this up? I've tried using OpenSSL's s_server, but it only seems to want to respond to GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `s_server` does not support POST requests, you should use **`socat`** instead of **`openssl s_server`**:

```
# socat -v OPENSSL-LISTEN:443,cert=mycert.pem,key=key.pem,verify=0,fork 'SYSTEM:/bin/echo HTTP/1.1 200 OK;/bin/echo;/bin/echo this-is-the-content-of-the-http-answer'
```

**Here are essential parameters:**

- `fork`: to loop for many requests
- `-v`: to display the POST data (and other stuff) to STDOUT
- `verify=0`: do not ask for mutual authentication

**Now, here is an example:**

We use the following POST request:

```
% wget -O - --post-data=abcdef --no-check-certificate https://localhost/
[...]
this-is-the-content-of-the-http-answer
```

We see the following `socat` output:

```
# socat -v OPENSSL-LISTEN:443,cert=mycert.crt,key=key.pem,verify=0,fork 'SYSTEM:/bin/echo HTTP/1.1 200 OK;/bin/echo;/bin/echo this-is-the-content-of-the-http-answer'
> 2017/08/05 03:13:04.346890  length=212 from=0 to=211
POST / HTTP/1.1\r
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.1 (freebsd10.3)\r
Accept: */*\r
Accept-Encoding: identity\r
Host: localhost:443\r
Connection: Keep-Alive\r
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r
Content-Length: 6\r
\r
< 2017/08/05 03:13:04.350299  length=16 from=0 to=15
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> 2017/08/05 03:13:04.350516  length=6 from=212 to=217
abcdef< 2017/08/05 03:13:04.351549  length=1 from=16 to=16

< 2017/08/05 03:13:04.353019  length=39 from=17 to=55
this-is-the-content-of-the-http-answer
```